# Namespace not found after successful installation of NuGet package?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2022 .NET 7 MAUI Class Library project named **HybridScanner**.

I'm importing the [ZXing.Net.Maui](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui) NuGet package.

The NuGet package installs successfully.

However I'm unable to use it in my library. I'm getting the error:

> The type or namespace name 'PackageName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

The NuGet package works fine in a .NET MAUI app project.

After some investigations, I noticed the following:

[image]

What does that mean? Does it mean the NuGet package is not availbale for `net7.0` while my project tries to build against it?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NuGet package [ZXing.Net.Maui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Maui) (currently in version `0.3.0-preview.1`) targets these frameworks:

- net7.0-android33.0
- net7.0-ios16.0
- net7.0-maccatalyst15.4
- net7.0-windows10.0.19041

All of these are *OS-specific TFMs* ([target framework moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/frameworks)).
However, the platform-agnostic TFM for .NET 7.0, `net7.0`, is not supported.

To solve your issue in the consuming project, you either have to remove the `net7.0` target from the `TargetFrameworks` *PropertyGroup*; or guard the usages of contained symbols with [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) conditionally.

In your case, either change the `.csproj` from

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0;net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

to

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

or
you conditionally compile the usages of this library

```cs
#if (ANDROID || IOS || MACCATALYST)
using ZXing.Net.Maui;
#endif
```